# calculate percentage for the data at the end in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, percentage

I need to calculate profit/loss percentage for closing prices over the given n days.
df is the data frame. Close Price is the closing price

```
def profit_loss(days):
    last = df[-1:]['Close Price']
    begin = df[-days:-(days-1)]['Close Price']
    return ((last-begin)/last)*100
```

the function is supposed to given the required percentage. If the days are given, the function takes the last day closing price and the last nth day closing price and calculate the profit/loss percentage. My output is giving me NaN as output

```
profit_loss(7)
```

The output is;

```
487   NaN
493   NaN
Name: Close Price, dtype: float64
```

The expected output is `-0.0102`.
The closing price data for the last 7 days is

```
[970.20,981.75,979.95,980.50,980.45,975.35,979.10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you are getting `NaN` values your your output is because the `last` and `begin` variables are of type `Series`. Try adding `.item()`, which will return the `float` values.

```
last = df[-1:]['Close Price'].item()
begin = df[-days:-(days-1)]['Close Price'].item()
```

Comment: You're welcome. I kindly ask that you please mark the answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of slicing your data in order to get a single element (which gives you `Series`, as Kurt Kline pointed out), you should simply get the element of interest:

```
def profit_loss(days):
    last = df['Close Price'][-1]
    begin = df['Close Price'][-days]
    return ((last-begin)/last)*100
```

This also fixes a bug: in the original code, if `days`=1, then you take Close Prices for days `[-1:0]`, which is no day at all—since this slice starts from the last element (-1) and tries to go down to the first element (0).